# Managing Rails Migrations for different branches on the same machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, migration, rails-migrations

I'm a one-man-band at the company I work for. I develop a Rails application for internal use within the company. Since the beginning of the project I have used SVN for source control and done most, but not all, development in trunk. Occasionally, when I have had very significant changes to make, I have branched and made the changes merging back in when done. All very typical.

However, none of those "significant changes" that I have had to make have ever touched the database migrations. They have always been view/controller stuff.

In this situation, with one development box, how do I play around with migrations and various database changes that I may or may not keep? I don't want to have to remember to revert all the migrations back to the beginning of the branch before I throw the branch out if it doesn't work.

I have considered setting up special development environments and databases (`app_branch` instead of `app_development`) but that seems to work strongly against the notion of "easy branching" that experimental development tends to rely on.

Are there best practices for this situation? What are others out there doing in this situation?

Comment: Great question.  If you don't mind your dev database being empty all the time (perhaps some development seed data may be in order) you can just checkout the new branch and run `rake db:schema:load` which will clobber the development and rebuild it from the current `db/schema.rb`.

Answer (score 3):

I try hard to keep my development database "droppable."  If I lose it all - no big deal.  My migrations are ready to build it up again from scratch and there's always a script with seed / test data in it somewhere.  I guess it's not especially clever.

If I needed a new branch for database work, I would just check it out, drop, create, rake, and then seed.  I guess I'd write a script to get it done because when I go to adandon the branch, I'm going to have to go through the same process again from the trunk.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your schema.rb file is in version control. That way, as you switch branches, you can drop your DB and then do rake db:schema:load as necessary.

Also, you really should switch to Git. It will make branch management a lot easier than SVN. (I speak from lots of experience with both programs.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to have different schemas, you'll need multiple databases. "Easy branching" refers to source control, typically, and not databases.  As far as I know there's no easy way to branch databases like you would branch in, say, git.

One thing we do to manage our dev/production branches is we check our current git branch in our database.yml file.  If the current branch is production, we use one database, otherwise we use our dev database. something along the lines of this:

```
<% if 'git branch' =~ /^\* production/
    db = 'production_database'
   else
    db = 'development_database
end %>

development:
    database: <% db %>
```

Note, the 'production_database' refers to a local version of the production schema, not the live production database.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script for dealing with this exact problem. It is based around git, but you could easily change it to work for svn:

https://gist.github.com/4076864

Given a branch name it will:

1. Roll back any migrations on your current branch which do not exist on the given branch
2. Discard any changes to the db/schema.rb file
3. Check out the given branch
4. Run any new migrations existing in the given branch
5. Update your test database

I find myself manually doing this all the time on our project, so I thought it'd be nice to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

If I am creating a branch where you are making siginificant changes, you can create a copy of the database *before* creating your migrations then change the `development` section of database.yml inside the branch.  Leave your `:production` section alone and then decide which version of the database you want to keep for future development when you merge the branch back into the trunk.

We do this with feature releases.  I'll have local DBs for version 1, 2, 3 like "db_v1", db_v2", etc.  As we roll through the versions, each subsequent development branch gets an edit in `database.yml` while the trunk stays on the last version for bug fixing.

Comment: Why? This is what schema.rb already does if you use it properly.

Comment: schema.rb helps with the structure of the DB if you're willing to rebuild your database, but it doesn't help if you are actively flipping branches and want to maintain the development data you've built up for each branch.

Comment: "If you're willing to rebuild your database" -- why wouldn't you be? That's the proper solution. Development data should be ephemeral, but you can always use yaml_db or something to export what you need and reload it after schema change.

I could imagine multiple DBs such as you describe for use on a staging server where people are testing different versions at random (and thus all must be available simultaneously), but a setup like this on your local development machine suggests that you're not in enough control of your own development process, and are making your life harder as a result.

Comment: We're probably wandering into the world of opinion here... I generally like to keep some convenient data in my development environment while working on a particular branch that won't be needed when that particular bit of code is finally committed.  It's not a requirement for other developers to work, just a convenience while writing the code.  Clearly, YMMV.

Comment: Oh, I like to keep appropriate data in my dev DB too. But I also don't find that switching branches gets in the way of that. Have you actually run into problems, or is this theoretical?

Comment: I've definitely hit this when dropping columns in one branch then having to toggle back to the other and expecting the data to still be there.  It's VERY rare that I do this in my day to day work, but it has happened a couple of times, hence the answer to the original question.

Comment: Yeah, I've experienced that too, but only once or twice. I think one reason that I experience this so rarely is that when switching branches, I usually run migrations only if the Rails application complains. That means that "extra" columns that the current branch doesn't know about are usually not dropped, which causes fewer problems on switching. This isn't immutable practice, just laziness. :)